# Zeroing elements of a sparse matrix, based on another matrix (Matrix Package)

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have `W` which is a 4 million row binary sparse matrix. I am using the **Matrix** package.
I would like to be able to compute the following:

```
W2 = W %*% W             #W2 becomes a dgCMatrix
W2@x[ W2@x > 1 ] = 1
W2 = W2 - W
W2@x[ W2@x < 0 ] = 0
```

Unfortunately the third line in this operation trashes my computer completely. I am able to compute lines (1) and (2) just fine, but when I try to compute line (3) R demands much more RAM than I have available. I am sure that `W2 - W` is "more sparse" than `W2` alone.

Is there any algorithm in vector form that allows to zero the positions of `W2` which are 1 in `W`?  Is there any efficient way to implement this in R?

Comment: I revised to help others avoid the same interpretation error that I had.  The 2nd and 4th lines are trivial.  The 3rd line is the key one.  It's not too hard to solve this if you map to a univariate coordinate list.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming a 4,000,000x4,000,000 Matrix, otherwise line 1 would return the error 'A and B inner dimensions must match'.

I am having difficulties replicating your problems.  See below.

```
> library(Matrix)
> W<-rsparsematrix(nrow=4000000,ncol=4000000,density = .0000001)
> W<-W>0
> str(W)
Formal class 'lgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  ..@ i       : int [1:1600000] 623428 717198 3216269 3398149 3888958 3970651 3106201 61257 370389 3031066 ...
  ..@ p       : int [1:4000001] 0 2 3 3 4 5 6 6 6 7 ...
  ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 4000000 4000000
  ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : NULL
  ..@ x       : logi [1:1600000] TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE ...
  ..@ factors : list()
> W2 <- W %*% W
> str(W2)
Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  ..@ i       : int [1:638322] 908991 1031349 2979756 1924552 3421130 992757 1375889 2872056 3161609 3389210 ...
  ..@ p       : int [1:4000001] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 4000000 4000000
  ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : NULL
  ..@ x       : num [1:638322] 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 ...
  ..@ factors : list()     
> W2@x[ W2@x > 1 ] = 1
> W2 = W2 - W
> W2@x[ W2@x < 0 ] = 0
> str(W2)
Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  ..@ i       : int [1:2238320] 623428 717198 3216269 3398149 3888958 3970651 3106201 61257 370389 908991 ...
  ..@ p       : int [1:4000001] 0 2 3 3 4 5 6 6 6 7 ...
  ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 4000000 4000000
  ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : NULL
  ..@ x       : num [1:2238320] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
  ..@ factors : list()
```

Significantly, your line 2 does nothing in my example, because W %*% W is only returning 1's and 0's.